# Visual Basic number range

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to complete an assignment but I'm a little lost in the logic here. I'm trying to create a range for a kWh rate to applied for but can't seem to come up with anything. I'm new to vb and programming.

[image]

```
    Dim stateTax As Decimal = 3.5
    Dim cityTax As Decimal = 1.5
    Dim kWhUsed As Decimal = txtkWhUsed.Text
    Dim kWhRate As Decimal

    Select Case True
        Case (kWhUsed < 1000)
            kWhRate = 0.052
            RunTotalPrice = (kWhRate * kWhUsed)

        Case (kWhUsed >= 1000)
            kWhRate = 0.041
            RunTotalPrice = RunTotalPrice + (kWhRate * kWhUsed)



    End Select
    txtAmtDue.Text = FormatCurrency(RunTotalPrice.ToString, 2)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Select Case` since it does top down logic testing for you.

```
Dim kWhRate As Double
Select Case kWhUsed
  Case < 1000
     kWhRate = 0.052
  Case < 2000
     kWhRate = 0.041
  'etc.
End Select
```

Comment: So I should scrap the if statement?

Comment: This way is better when there are more than 2 choices. If statements as are great for simple boolean choices. What you end up doing is up to use we are here to make suggestions.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I'm still having issues though. I've updated my code as shown above. Not sure how to add the two prices once it exceeds 1,000. For example, the first 1,000 used it should be $0.052 per kWh, but if it exceeds that it is $0.041 for the next 300 kWh. How would I logistically code this?

Comment: Your Select Case is not the same as mine. Then just run the calculation after the Select Case.